# What is the proper way to overwrite the initialize method when calling Model.create?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

What is the proper way to overwrite the `initialize` method when calling `Model.create`? I tried:

```
Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize params, foo
```

intending it to be called like this:

```
Model.create foo:'bar'
```

Not using Rails, but using ActiveRecord.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I realize this question is poorly worded. What I really wanted to know is how to override the `create` method.

Comment: @BSeven Could please provide a concrete example of how you want to use the overrided `create`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better get away from that path!

If you need a different behavior to create a model object just create a different method like:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_with_foo params, foo
    model = self.new params
    # Do whatever you want with foo for example
    model.foo = true if foo == :foo
    model.save
    model # return the created model object
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo: 'bar'` is a single argument: a hash. It is a shorthand for `{foo: 'bar'}`, which is further a shorthand for `{:foo => 'bar'}`. So if you want to use it like that, you just need to define it so that it takes one argument.